# nginx map with regular expression ate my URI

Tags: nginx

Some map kill my URI, I do not get why:

```
map $http_cookie $redir_scheme {
    default http;
    ~some=value https; # here is the SSL cookie
}
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  redir.*;

    expires -1;
    add_header Last-Modified "";

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $redir_scheme://example.com/$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Curl give a redirect without URI:

```
$ curl -giH 'Host: redir.somedomain.com' 'localhost:8888/some/path/with/meaningful/data' -H 'Cookie: some=value'
(...)
Location: https://example.com/
(...)
```

But when I change the configuration to:

```
map $http_cookie $redir_scheme {
    default http;
    some=value https; # here is the SSL cookie
}
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  redir.*;

    expires -1;
    add_header Last-Modified "";

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $redir_scheme://example.com/$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Curl gives a redirect with a URI:

```
$ curl -giH 'Host: redir.somedomain.com' 'localhost:8888/some/path/with/meaningful/data' -H 'Cookie: some=value'
(...)
Location: https://example.com/some/path/with/meaningful/data
(...)
```

I guess the first solution was really dumb, but I can't see why.
Do you have any light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `$1` comes from the last regular expression executed. As `map{}` is checked later than the regular expression in rewrite, the `$1` comes from the regular expression specified in the map (and it's empty). There is a [ticket 564](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/564) in nginx trac about this - while the behaviour is formally correct, it's clearly counter-intuitive and needs to be changed.

As a workaround you can use named captures instead:

```
rewrite ^/(?<rest>.*)$ $redir_scheme://example.com/$rest redirect;
```

Or, better yet, just use `return` with $request_uri instead:

```
return 302 $redir_scheme://example.com$request_uri;
```

Comment: wow, that's unexpected. Thanks a lot for this thorough explanation.